# Materialize grid contents creates gap

Tags: html, css, materialize

I've created a video gallery using the MaterializeCSS Framework. This is how it looks below: [Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMRTQ.png)

I've noticed however, if I should change the images within cards in the 4th column from the bird image, there is a gap created. See image below:
[Gallery with gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWSs8.png)

What could be causing this? All the html content for the cards are duplicates. I've only changed some of the images

HTML:

```
    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img2.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img3.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img2.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img2.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> HOW TO WATCH THIS MOVIE3</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img4.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s3">

        <div class="card z-depth-4">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="img/img2.jpg">
                <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light cyan activator"><i class="material-icons">more_horiz</i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content black">
                <span class="center-align video-title card-title white-text"> How to watch this movie</span>
                <div class="col s2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-reveal">
                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">HOW TO DO THIS<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell without your images. Try putting them in rows like this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/gRVXjR

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you it worked, but why? I've uploaded the images online and have added some of them to the code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLwOoN.

Comment: Sounds like it's because the columns are different heights, so floating doesn't work when the rows wrap. Defining a unique row will clear the floats from the previous row and won't cause columns to stack like that.